# What is proper way to fill fields which are auto generated depending on other ones

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-autoform

I'm using AutoForm for forms and SimpleSchema with Collection2 to schema.

In my schema there are some fields which are generated during document insert/creation and are able to change later on.

When it's the best place to generate data and put into database?

1. Write needed code using `autoValue` directly in schema.
2. Use AutoForm Hooks.
3. Do it using `matb33:collection-hooks` before/after.insert hooks.

What's are pluses and minuses in each case?

Answer (score 0):

I Would say the following:

1. Use autoValue by default if you want set or change a specific field.
2. The AutoForm hooks are specific for forms and not used as global hooks.
3. matb33:collection-hooks are perfect if you want to trigger some logic which isnt specific for a field.

typically I use autoValue for automatically setting the loggedInUser, createdAtDate, updatedAtDate.. etc and I use matb3:collection-hooks for example when I create a user and and I automatically want to create a event log in the database.

Hope it helps you.